# Excel - Insert a comment issue : greyed/not available

Tags: excel, windows

I have a weird issue in Excel. We are a little company with 15 computers on Windows 10 and Office 2016/2019. The server is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and ESET Endpoint Security 7.

We can't insert comments at all since 1 week ago. This is happening on every Excel sheet, even on a blank one.

I tried to reinstall Office with no success.

[image: here's the screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some update has removed that from right click menu.
However you can still add comment by SHIFT + F2